# How to fill a column conditionally to values in an other column being in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas dataframe, how to fill the value of a column conditionally to values in an other  column being part of a list ?

This is very similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas), but when I apply:

```
df['type'] = np.where(df['food'] in ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'], 'fruit', 'oth. food')
```

I got an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I suppose the `in` operator has been not overridden to work with vectors..

Comment: Are you after `df['type'] = np.where(df['food'].isin(['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']), 'fruit', 'oth. food')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work

```
df['type'] = np.where(df['food'].isin(['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']), 'fruit', 'oth. food')
```

Comment: :) only 20 seconds is between our posts. Nice.

Comment: @jezrael: thanks both.. I would love I could add both as accepted answers ;-)

Comment: yeah, if only you could add both :-)

Comment: I think what can I do in your skin - maybe only upvote both solutions. But you lost `+2`, hmmm. But it is up to you, what do you do.

Comment: No problem. Nice day.

Comment: I think that it is not problem with accepting MedAli solution. Thank you for upvoting. Difference 20 seconds is nearly the same. :P

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['type'] = np.where(df['food'].isin(['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']), 'fruit', 'oth. food')
```