# Use a list to conditionally fill a new column based on values in multiple columns

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to populate a new column within a pandas dataframe by using values from several columns. The original columns are either `0` or '1' with exactly a single `1` per series. The new column would correspond to df['A','B','C','D'] by populating `new_col = [1, 3, 7, 10]` as shown below. (A `1` at `A` means `new_col = 1`; if `B=1`,`new_col = 3`, etc.)

```
df    
         A    B    C    D
1        1    0    0    0
2        0    0    1    0
3        0    0    0    1
4        0    1    0    0
```

The new `df` should look like this.

```
df    
         A    B    C    D   new_col
1        1    0    0    0         1
2        0    0    1    0         7
3        0    0    0    1        10
4        0    1    0    0         3
```

I've tried to use `map`, `loc`, and `where` but can't seem to formulate an efficient way to get it done. Problem seems very close [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551128/how-to-fill-a-column-conditionally-to-values-in-an-other-column-being-in-a-list). A couple other posts I've looked at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226488/python-pandas-change-one-value-based-on-another-value) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas). None of these show how to use multiple columns conditionally to fill a new column based on a list.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few ways, mostly involving `argmax` or `idxmax`, to get either an ndarray or a Series which we can use to fill the column.

We could drop down to `numpy`, find the maximum locations (where the 1s are) and use those to index into an array version of new_col:

```
In [148]: np.take(new_col,np.argmax(df.values,1))
Out[148]: array([ 1,  7, 10,  3])
```

We could make a Series with new_col as the values and the columns as the index, and index into that with idxmax:

```
In [116]: pd.Series(new_col, index=df.columns).loc[df.idxmax(1)].values
Out[116]: array([ 1,  7, 10,  3])
```

We could use get_indexer to turn the column idxmax results into integer offsets we can use with new_col:

```
In [117]: np.array(new_col)[df.columns.get_indexer(df.idxmax(axis=1))]
Out[117]: array([ 1,  7, 10,  3])
```

Or (and this seems very wasteful) we could make a new frame with the new columns and use idxmax directly:

```
In [118]: pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=new_col).idxmax(1)
Out[118]: 
0     1
1     7
2    10
3     3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but for me it beats the if/elif/elif loop:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 7, 'D': 10}
def new_col(row):
    k = row[row == 1].index.tolist()[0]
    return d[k]

df['new_col'] = df.apply(new_col, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   new_col
1   1   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   1   0   7
3   0   0   0   1   10
4   0   1   0   0   3
```