# Conditionally fill a column of a pandas df with values of a different df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two differently shaped df. One contains **words** and their **frequencies**, the other contains **words** and their **lemmas**.

The first df maps always one word to one frequency,
the second df maps many words to one lemma (multiple times). E.g.:

df1:

```
  word  frequency
    de   33504559
   que   32700217
    no   28263302
     a   21978600
    la   21249418
```

and df2:

```
     lemma       word
   zurullo   zurullos
  zurupeto  zurupetos
    zutano     zutana
    zutano    zutanas
    zutano    zutanos
```

---

I would like to add the lemma information to `df1`, by searching each word of  `df1`, comparing it to the words in `df2`, and pulling the lemma information from `df2` to add it back to `df1`.

---

There are useful answers for [when the value is always the same in df1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas), but since I want to do this for each row that each contains a different word, I am not sure how to proceed. (I checked [the merging and concatenating docs section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) but resurfaced more confused than before...)

In just-python I would use loops, e.g.:

```
new_df = dict()
# assuming all dfs are dicts
for w, f in df1.items():
    if w in df2.keys():
        new_df[w] = (df2[w], f)
```

Would be happy to learn more about this using pandas dataframe operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='word')
```