# Perform a conditional operation on a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that this should be simple, but I want to take a column from a pandas
dataframe, and for only the entries which meet some condition (say less than 1),
multiply by a scalar (say 2).

For example, in this dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),index='A B C D E'.split(),columns='W X Y Z'.split())

          W         X       Y        Z  

A    2.706850 0.628133 0.907969 0.503826 
B    0.651118 -0.319318 -0.848077 0.605965 
C    -2.018168 0.740122 0.528813 -0.589001 
D    0.188695 -0.758872 -0.933237 0.955057 
E    0.190794 1.978757 2.605967 0.683509
```

if I'm interested in carrying out this operation on column `W`, the result should be

```
          W         X       Y        Z  

A    2.706850 0.628133 0.907969 0.503826 
B    1.302236 -0.319318 -0.848077 0.605965 
C    -4.036336 0.740122 0.528813 -0.589001 
D    0.37739 -0.758872 -0.933237 0.955057 
E    0.381588 1.978757 2.605967 0.683509
```

I have the below for an absolute assignment:

```
df.loc[df['W'] < 1, 'W'] = 4
```

but I'm not sure how to use the actual values from `W`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, just use the `*=` operator to make your multiplication in place:

If your Original dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
          W         X         Y         Z
0  2.706850  0.628133  0.907969  0.503826
1  0.651118 -0.319318 -0.848077  0.605965
2 -2.018168  0.740122  0.528813 -0.589001
3  0.188695 -0.758872 -0.933237  0.955057
4  0.190794  1.978757  2.605967  0.683509
```

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['W'] < 1, 'W'] *= 2
```

resulting in this:

```
>>> df
          W         X         Y         Z
0  2.706850  0.628133  0.907969  0.503826
1  1.302236 -0.319318 -0.848077  0.605965
2 -4.036336  0.740122  0.528813 -0.589001
3  0.377390 -0.758872 -0.933237  0.955057
4  0.381588  1.978757  2.605967  0.683509
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
df.loc[df['W'] < 1, 'W'] = df.loc[df['W'] < 1, 'W'] * 2
```

Comment: It's kind of interesting that even `df.loc[df['W'] < 1, 'W'] = df['W'] * 2` works.

Comment: @unutbu, Yes, it's something I've never fully grasped. Sometimes you need to apply the mask on the left AND right, sometimes not.

Comment: Its the intersection of indices.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['W'] = numpy.where(df['W'] < 1, df['W'] * 2, df['W'])
```

It checks for your condition and applies the relevant operation.

Comment: Or `df.W *= np.where(df.W < 1, 2, 1)`