# Python list comprehension if else statement and shift

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, list-comprehension, shift

Let's assume I have a df like this

```
Signal.   COND1.    COND2
  NO        1.        1
  NO        1         3
  NO        4         2
```

I would like to be able to have a list comprehension that overwrites the Signal column by using the following condition

```
Write "GO" if COND1_t-1 < COND2_t-1 and COND1_t0 > COND2_to
```

I tried sth like this

```
 df_in['SIGNAL'] = ['GO' for n in df_in['SIGNAL'] if ((df_in['COND1'].shift(1) < df_in['COND2'].shift(1)) & (df_in['COND1'] > df_in['COND2']))]
```

But I am getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Your `Signal` column is dected as a boolean by pandas. You want to change only some values, so the whole column type will no change. Try forcing the column to be str type.

Comment: Does `DataFrame.where` solve your problem?

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux I don't think that's the problem. `df_in['COND1'].shift()` returns a column, as does `df_in['COND2'].shift()`. The result of the boolean expression is a column, so you can't run an `if` on it. OP, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas) should answer your question though.