# How to change multiple column values with np.where?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'line amount#1': [0.21, 0.13, 0.1], 'line amount#2': [0.0, 0.05, .05], 'ExclBTW': [0.5, 0.18, .05]}
dftaxitems = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dftaxitems


line amount#1   line amount#2   ExclBTW
0   0.21                0.00    0.50
1   0.13                0.05    0.18
2   0.10                0.05    0.05
```

Now, I want to change all values of line amounts to np.nan when they do not add up to the BTW column and keep the value when they do add up.

So I want to do it dynamically because the line amounts may be up to 10 lines large.

However getting the following error with the following code:

```
#change line amount if not totalling into ExclBTW:
dfchecklineamount = dftaxitems.filter(like='line amount').astype(float)
dfchecklineamount['sum'] = dfchecklineamount[list(dfchecklineamount.columns)].sum(axis=1)
dfchecklineamount['check'] = np.where(dfchecklineamount['sum'].astype(float) == dfresult['ExclBTW'].astype(float),True, False)

dfchecklineamount['check'] = np.where(dfchecklineamount['sum'].astype(float) == dfresult['ExclBTW'].astype(float),True, False)
colstochange = dfchecklineamount.filter(regex ='line amount').columns
dfchecklineamount[colstochange] = np.where(dfchecklineamount['check'] == False, np.nan,dfchecklineamount[colstochange] )







 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) () (2,4)
```

Please help!

Desired output:

```
line amount#1   line amount#2   ExclBTW
0   np.nan             np.nan    0.50
1   0.13                0.05     0.18
2   np.nan             np.nan     0.05
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas) would this help ?

Comment: will do @sammywemmy

Comment: @AmriRasyidi that is for one column unfortunately.

Comment: are you sure the last line of your expected line to be NaN? 0.1 + 0.05 >= 0.05

Comment: Try extra [] on 'check' - `np.where(dfchecklineamount[['check']] == False, np.nan,dfchecklineamount[colstochange] )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `sum` over `axis=1` then we set the values to `NaN` with [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
lines = dftaxitems.filter(like="line")
m = lines.sum(axis=1).ne(dftaxitems["ExclBTW"])
dftaxitems[lines.columns] = lines.mask(m)
```

```
   line amount#1  line amount#2  ExclBTW
0            NaN            NaN     0.50
1           0.13           0.05     0.18
2            NaN            NaN     0.05
```

Comment: this seemed like the excellent solution however coming up with different results.. Line amounts are NaN'd when they shouldn't be

Comment: Can you adjust your example data to reproduce the problem. The given one right now gives correct results

Comment: My values were non-float so had to use .astype(float)

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT:*** Adding more Generic solution which handles any number of similar lineamount columns

```
c = dftaxitems.filter(like='line amount#').columns
m = dftaxitems[c].sum(1).eq(dftaxitems['ExclBTW'])
dftaxitems.loc[~m, c] = np.nan
dftaxitems
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Simple explanation would be: we can use boolean indexing to fill the NaN values. First get mask in m variable(where we are checking condition if sum of 2 columns are equals to 3rd column), then using loc function to set NaN values accordingly.

```
m = (dftaxitems['line amount#1'] + dftaxitems['line amount#2']) == dftaxitems['ExclBTW']

dftaxitems.loc[~m, ['line amount#1', 'line amount#2']] = np.nan
dftaxitems
```

Output will be as follows:

```
   line amount#1  line amount#2  ExclBTW
0            NaN            NaN     0.50
1           0.13           0.05     0.18
2            NaN            NaN     0.05
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer : Could you make the line amount bit dynamic because I want to do it dynamically because the line amounts may be up to 10 lines large.

Comment: @Max, sure, please do give me a min or 2, will post it.

Comment: @Max, could you please do check my EDIT answer and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Erfan, may be  logic is same(which could be for many) but implementation is totally different, which can't be said copy IMHO, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
dftaxitems['line amount#1'] = np.where(dftaxitems['line amount#1'] + dftaxitems['line amount#1'] >= dftaxitems['ExclBTW'], dftaxitems['line amount#1'], np.nan)
dftaxitems['line amount#2'] = np.where(dftaxitems['line amount#1'] + dftaxitems['line amount#1'] >= dftaxitems['ExclBTW'], dftaxitems['line amount#2'], np.nan)
```

I use this, but there must be a better way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'line amount#1': [0.21, 0.13, 0.1], 'line amount#2': [0.0, 0.05, .05], 'ExclBTW': [0.5, 0.18, .05]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

df['line amount#1'] = df['line amount#1'].where(df['line amount#1'] + df['line amount#2'] == df['ExclBTW'], other=np.nan)
df['line amount#2'] = df['line amount#1'].where(df['line amount#1'] + df['line amount#2'] == df['ExclBTW'], other=np.nan)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   line amount#1  line amount#2  ExclBTW
0           0.21           0.00     0.50
1           0.13           0.05     0.18
2           0.10           0.05     0.05

   line amount#1  line amount#2  ExclBTW
0            NaN            NaN     0.50
1           0.13           0.13     0.18
2            NaN            NaN     0.05
```

Comment: So I want to do it dynamically because the line amounts may be up to 10 lines large.